# Error for different type of list declaration in STL c++

Tags: c++, list, stl

```
list<int>L[]=new list<int>[20];
```

This gives an error " array initializer must be an initializer
      list"
What is wrong with initializing list like:

`list<int> L[100];`

Also does list[] L mean anything

`list<int> *L=new list<int>[20]`
Why does this work ?

Please give me brief explaination for each of the cases if possible as I am new to STL

Comment: Probably useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c

Comment: 1) Don't do it, use `std::array<std::list<int>, 20>` (static allocation) or `std::vector<std::list<int>>` (ability to change amount of lists) 
2) If you _really_ wanna try something that strange, `new` allocates memory into a pointer (explained in short), you also need to call `delete[] L` afterwards. Your first attempt is just incorrect.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to do? Are you trying to store _one_ list of `int`s, or do you need `20` lists of `int`? There's also very likely no need for manual memory allocation. A basic `list<int>` or `vector<int>` or even `list<list<int>>` should work fine for you.

Comment: @alterigel I am trying to create a adjacency list . I need to initialize an array of list and the size of list will be given later

Comment: @mathnormie Ah, ok. The normal approach here would be to use a `vector<vector<int>>`.

Comment: This is C++, not Java. `new` does not do the same thing as you may expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new list<int>[20]` dynamically allocates an array of 20 `list<int>` objects, and returns a `list<int>*` pointer.  So you need a `list<int>*` variable to receive that pointer:

```
list<int> *L = new list<int>[20];
...
delete[] L;
```

`list<int> L[]` does not declare a pointer, it declares a static array of unspecified size.  The only thing you can assign to that is an initializer list containing the desired array elements, so the compiler can deduce the array's size:

```
list<int> L[] = {a_list_object, another_list_object, ...};
```

`list<int> L[100];` declares a static array of 100 `list<int>` objects.  No pointers are involved.